# How to add content security policy to microsoft edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to load some 'https://' sites but this error blocking content  'CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'connect-src 'self' ....... Resource will be blocked.'

Comment: What is your code to set CSP?

Comment: Can you please provide detailed information like how exactly you tried to load the HTTPS site? How did you get this error? Please try to provide any sample code or steps to reproduce the issue. It will be helpful for us to understand the issue in a better way. thanks for your understanding.